# New Relic with Kaazing

Tags: java, newrelic, kaazing

Is it possible to monitor kaazing jms gateway using New Relic on MAC OS. If yes, can anyone share the steps involved.

I tried to run my app with javaagent as

```
java -javaagent:~/GATEWAY_HOME/newrelic/newrelic.jar ~/GATEWAY_HOME/bin/gateway.start
```

but getting the error as

```
 objc[2350]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.     
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
8 21, 2014 11:07:10 +0900 [2350 1] com.newrelic INFO: Agent is using Logback
8 21, 2014 11:07:10 +0900 [2350 1] com.newrelic INFO: Loading configuration file "/Users/xxx/GATEWAY_HOME/newrelic/./newrelic.yml"
Error: Could not find or load main class .Users.xxx.GATEWAY_HOME.bin.gateway.start
```

Can someone tell me, what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this call `.Users.xxx.GATEWAY_HOME.bin.gateway.start` is to a method not a class path.  What *does* your class path look like currently?

I would expect something like this: `-classpath /Library/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar` with the name of your dispatcher replacing tomcat.

If you do `echo $CLASSPATH` what do you get back?

Comment: When i do $CLASS_PATH its blank, but directories paths appear when i do echo $PATH like, /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/

Comment: If that's the case then explicitly set CLASSPATH so that it will point to where the newrelic.jar file lives.